# MySQL primary key

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Quiero hacer que al insertar un bloque de datos en una base de datos, pero que mi Primary Key sea la misma para ese bloque de datos, y se incremente cuando se termine de insertar

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: A qué le llamas "un bloque de datos"?

Comment: explica mejor por favor

Comment: Si, tipo de que como insertamos varios renglones pero como si fuera un solo evento, y como identificador uso la primary key, pero para hacer query quiero usar como paramentro la primary key y que me traiga todo lo que tiene la misma primary key

Comment: La llave primaria no se puede repetir entre distintos registros de una tabla. Esa es justamente la idea, que el valor de los campos que componen la llave sea único entre todos los registros, para poder identificar, a través de ella, a uno y solo un registro. Lo que describes es perfectamente válido, pero no con la llave primaria.

Comment: Dices: **"mi Primary Key sea la misma para ese bloque de datos"** si es la misma... ya no es PK... la PK de cada registro debe ser única... Si no es eso, pues... si formulas con mas detalle tu pregunta, te darán respuestas concretas.

Answer (score 1):

Las **claves primarias son únicas**, por ende, irrepetibles. Yo te recomendaría usar un **indice**.

Una forma podrías ser la siguiente:

1. Crear una tabla para agrupar los datos, por ejemplo:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `datos_grupos` (
     `idGrupo` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `nombre` tinytext COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

   ALTER TABLE `datos_grupos`
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

   ALTER TABLE `datos_grupos`
     MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
   ```

   **Nota**: Esta tabla tiene una clave primaria auto incremental.
2. Crear una tabla para los registros a ser ser agrupados

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `datos` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `dato` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
     `idGrupo` int(11) NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

   ALTER TABLE `datos`
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     ADD KEY `idGrupo` (`idGrupo`);

   ALTER TABLE `datos`
     ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
   ```

   **Nota**: Esta tabla tiene un clave primaria auto incremental. También una clave tipo indice en la cual se debe guardar el indice de referencia a la primer tabla
3. Con estas 2 tablas, antes de insertar el primer grupo de datos, deberias crear un grupo y a cada dato indicarle el grupo. Ejemplo:

   ```
   # Creamos el primer grupo
   INSERT INTO `datos_grupos` (`nombre`) VALUES ('grupo 1');
   set @idGrupo = last_insert_id();

   # Por cada dato
   INSERT INTO `datos` (`nombre`, `idGrupo`) VALUES ('dato1', @idGrupo);
   ```
4. Por ultimo si quieres obtener todos los datos relacionados a un grupo, una opción seria:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM 'datos' WHERE idGrupo = 1
   ```

Comment: Es una respuesta correcta, pero por curiosisdad... ¿por qué lo haces como si fueses un SGBD?? Me refiero a lo de añadir las PK y las FK, y en la primera tabla... generas primero la PK (sin tener el atributo aún) y luego creas el atributo... Es solo curiosidad.

Comment: Es solo para dar una mejor visibilidad de cuales son los indices y claves de la tabla. Tambien, si las tablas existieran y los indices y claves no, se podria usar `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS..` y solo asegurar la creación de los mismos.

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría saber en que motor de base de datos trabajas.

Porque algunos de ellas tienen herramientas como hacerlo gráfico y luego generar el código.

Pero por si acaso:

```
CREATE TABLE PROFESOR(
     ID          INT          NOT NULL ***IDENTITY*** PRIMARY KEY,
     NOMBRE      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     APELLIDO    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     EDAD        INT          NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO PROFESOR(NOMBRE, APELLIDO, EDAD) VALUES
     (‘Miguel’,’Cervantes’,23),
     (‘Augusto’,’Munch’,32),
     (‘Minerva’,’Fredson’,29);
```

Extraido de: *http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/05/sql-server-indentity/*

Comment: Hola @Vicete, intenté entrar  la liga que mencionas, sin embargo no puedo, ¿se habrá roto la liga?

Comment: Me parece que si, no se si eliminar el enlace

Answer (score -1):

Para poder hacer lo que quieres tienes que crearte una variable, esta ha de contener el valor de tu Primary Key.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Tabla_01 (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    campo1 VARCHAR(100),
    campo2 varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Tabla_02 (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    idT1 int NOT NULL,
    campo1 VARCHAR(100),
    campo2 varchar(100)
);


set @ident=1;

insert into Tabla_01 (id,campo1,campo2)
Values (@ident,'ValorCampo1','ValorCampo2');

insert into Tabla_02 (id,idT1,campo1,campo2)
values
(1,@ident,'ValorCampo1','ValorCampo2'),
(2,@ident,'ValorCampo1','ValorCampo2'),
(3,@ident,'ValorCampo1','ValorCampo2');

set @ident=@ident+1;

insert into Tabla_02 (id,idT1,campo1,campo2)
values
(1,@ident,'ValorCampo1','ValorCampo2'),
(2,@ident,'ValorCampo1','ValorCampo2'),
(3,@ident,'ValorCampo1','ValorCampo2');
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo en [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/625960/1).

Comment: bienvenido a StackOverflow, en este sitio el espacio _Tu Respuesta_ está destinado a aquellos aportes que intentan responder directamente la pregunta o resolver el problema planteado por el OP. Una vez tengas la reputación mínima, podrás hacer comentarios en las preguntas y respuestas. Mientras tanto, te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y a visitar el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Lo siento, no me había dado cuenta. Mi intención era añadir un comentario.